# How to use image magick to generically convert images

Tags: image, imagemagick, jpeg, image-conversion

I want to convert images with generic extensions, I have this:

```
cat "$1" | convert 'jpeg:-' -resize '64x64' - | gsutil cp - "gs://images.xxx.com/${sha_sum}-64x64-${file_without_folder}"
```

the above works. But if I omit the 'jpeg:-' it won't work. Is there a way to generically convert any file type? Perhaps I need the 'jpeg:-' so that image magick knows what the file encoding type is? Is there a way for image magick to auto-detect the encoding perhaps?

I am looking to do this:

```
cat "$1" | convert -resize '64x64' - | gsutil cp - "gs://images.xxx.com/${sha_sum}-64x64-${file_without_folder}"
```

so that I can generically upload an image no matter the file type (encoding type).

Comment: Why do you need the cat "$1"?  Can't you just do `convert "$1" -resize '64x64' - | gsutil cp - "gs://images.xxx.com/${sha_sum}-64x64-${file_without_folder}"`?

Comment: Works for me, if by "omit" you mean "replace with - " : you need to specify the input file. If you're inputting from standard in, use `-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you still have to specify the input stream:

```
cat "$1" | convert - -resize '64x64' - | gsutil cp - "gs://images.xxx.com/${sha_sum}-64x64-${file_without_folder}"
```

I assume this is a minimal example and you really are required to read the image from standard in; if not, just specify the image directly:

```
convert "$1" -resize '64x64' - | gsutil cp - "gs://images.xxx.com/${sha_sum}-64x64-${file_without_folder}"
```

Note that not all formats can be detected from the stream data. Use

```
identify -list format
```

to see the types that can be read.

Comment: Personally to be explicit I like using `/dev/stdout` .. is there a way to specify `/dev/stdin` somehow?

Comment: Have you tried `/dev/stdin` ? You might also try `/proc/self/fd/0` and see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/how-portable-are-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-and-dev-stderr

Comment: have to support macos, so `/proc/pid/fd/0` won't work, but yeah I will try it

Comment: Hope it works, but also, IMO, the `-` is an explicit way of saying stdin. It's just not verbose or very human-readable.